# A $G$-action on $H$-fixed points

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with subgroup $H$. Let $M$ be a $kG$-module, and consider the $H$-fixed points $M^H$. Then this should surely not admit a $G$-action, as the $G$-action on $M$ does not preserve $H$-fixed points. Yet, consider the following:

$$ \operatorname{Hom}_{kG}(k \otimes_{kH} kG , M) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{kH}(k,M|_{H}) \cong M^H $$

The first isomorphism is just the induction--restriction adjunction, while the second isomorphism appears to be obvious. Yet the left-hand side clearly admits a $G$-action, hence so does $M^H$. What might this $G$-action be?

Answer (score 1):

I realise that I think I know the answer --- but I still hope that someone can factcheck me.

The summary is that $\operatorname{Hom}_{kG}(M,N)$ does not admit a 'natural' $G$-action, but it does admit a $G$-action when viewed as a subgroup of $\operatorname{Hom}_k(M,N)$, but from this perspective the $G$-action is trivial. That is:

- If $R$ is a commutative then, then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$ admits an $R$-action by defining $rf(m)$ to be $f(r \cdot m)$. This works fine because $R$ is commutative, and so it doesn't carry over to $kG$.
- $kG$-modules do have an internal Hom, but this internal Hom is $\operatorname{Hom}_k(M,N)$, with $G$-action given by $gf(v) = g \cdot f(g^{-1} v)$. Under this action, the $kG$-module maps are fixed points, and in that sense the $G$-action on $\operatorname{Hom}_{kG}(M,N)$ is trivial.